# Can I have Xcode/React Native automatically build schemas?

Tags: xcode, react-native

HI I'm not sure the title makes sense but I've found a weird pattern with my project. When I go to build, it basically goes one by one of things I've imported or Pods that I have any it can't find them.

I'm able to add them to the schema and build them, and then the error moves onto the next import/Pod. It feels like React Native doesn't know where to look for my imported files, but they're there... somewhere. Any ideas?

Here's a sample pattern:

1. Build main project
2. 'React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found
3. Add React schema & Build it
4. Build main project
5. 'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
6. Add Firebase schema & Build it
7. Build main project
8. Next unfound file...

The same is true for my Pods, it will say "framework not found for AppAuth"
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run pod update first and then pod install. I think it resolves your issue. it was because your package version is not latest.

Comment: @TalhaAkbar unfortunately the issue remains, I've removed pods, node_modules, etc. and reinstalled entirely.

Comment: It happens on any package/file, basically in the order they're called in AppDelegate, or in alphabetical order for the Pods. It seems as though my app can't "find" them.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's an issue with HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS or FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS? It seems they're being overwritten on build.